# Перевести число в систему счисления с основанием p

Tags: pascal

Вводится натуральное число n, не превосходящее 500. Требуется перевести его в систему счисления с основанием p (натуральное p также вводится, причём `2<=p<=10`) и вывести результат на экран.

Помогите, пожалуйста. Я не понимаю что нужно сделать в этой задаче. Что значит перевести n в систему счисления с основанием p?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите здесь: [Правила перевода чисел из одной системы счисления в другую](http://inf.e-alekseev.ru/text/Schisl_perevod.html).

> Перевод чисел из одной системы счисления в другую составляет важную часть машинной арифметики. Рассмотрим основные правила перевода.